# Is $B \vert A$, as in $P(B \vert A)$, an event?

Tags: probability

In probability theory, an event $A$ is defined to be a subset of the sample space $\Omega$, and $P(B|A)$ is defined to be $\frac{P(BA)}{P(A)}$, for all $B \subset \Omega$, when $P(A) \gt 0$.

My questions are:

Is it proved that, $B \vert A$ cannot be expressed via $A$ and $B$ using ordinary set operations (including but not limited to, union, intersection)? (I'm aware that $P(\cdot \vert A)$ is just a shift of sample space from $\Omega$ to $A$, it is $\cdot | A$ that I'm asking of, not $P(\cdot \vert A)$)

If it is not proved, what's your opinion on the reason why it hasn't been proved? Is it because that this is one of those "wrong" questions to ask? (assuming the existence of wrong questions)

And finally, is there any alternative formalization of conditional probability? like, somewhat include it as an axiom (I'm aware that a definition, in the sense that they are always true, is like an axiom), or define it another way (under some constraints, the alternative definition should be equivalent to the traditional definition given above).

And finally finally, can you point me to some interesting philosophical readings/debate about conditional probability?

Thanks :)

Comment: If $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$, $P(X)=|X|/3$ for $X\subset\Omega$, $A=\{a,b\}$, and $B=\{b\}$. Then $P(B|A)=\frac{1/3}{2/3}=1/2$. There is no event $X\subset\Omega$ for which $P(X)=1/2$.

Comment: This has been asked about before: $B|A$ does not exist, as an event or otherwise.

Comment: $P(B|A)$ is just a notation for conditional probability; as Did pointed out, $B|A$ is meaningless. (It would be like asking what the upper and right branches of the $+$ sign mean; only the full notation is meaningful.) Your closing questions are quite broad, and in any case should probably be in separate posts.

Comment: @zambawithkolbasa this is ... embarrassingly simple, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, a probability space is a triple $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$, where:

$\Omega$, the sample space, is the set of all possible outcomes,

$\mathcal F$, the set of all events, is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$,

$P$, the probability measure, is a function $P:\mathcal F \to [0,1]$ which assigns a probability to each event.

If $A\in \mathcal F$ is a particular event such that $P(A)\ne0$, then you can create a probability space
$(A, \mathcal F_A, P_A)$ where $\mathcal F_A = \{B\cap A: B \in \mathcal F \}$ and 
$P_A(B) = \frac{P(B)}{P(A)}$ for every $B$ in $\mathcal F_A$. In this scenario, for each $B$ in $\mathcal F$, $B|A$ would correspond to the event $B\cap A$ in $\mathcal F_A$ and $P(B|A) = P_A(B\cap A)$.

After saying all of that, no, $B|A$ does not correspond in a natural way to a member of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: theoritically beautiful :)